# RoR: How to modify the controller to accept update several params only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is the code generated by rails:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully updated.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@user) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

But I don't want user to update the whole user, assume that my user have fname, lname and gender, instead of remove the gender from the view, I want to restrict that the update method ONLY accept fname and lname only, if he/she want to update the gender, I won't allow him/her to do so. How can I restrict  the user to do so? thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you want this at the controller/model level? From my own experience I would try to prevent this using JavaScript or using multiple forms (one form for gender-update, one for the name-update, both use the same /update) - especially if you want to provide a solid XML API as well. "You can't change your name and gender at the same time" is really odd to read in an API documentation.

Answer (score 3):

or add a custom `@user.update_only()` method, which makes it also easier to reuse in different contexts...

```
class User
  def update_only(attrs = {}, *limit_to)
    update_attributes(attrs.delete_if { |k,v| !limit_to.include?(k.to_sym) })
  end
end
```

Then just do something along the lines of

```
@user.update_only(params[:user], :fname, :lname)
```

Comment: I must say I like this idea. It would be a nice extension to ActiveRecord (or perhaps a nice extension to update_attributes, using an :except hash perhaps).

Comment: and it transparently handles attr_protected/accessible as well - feel free to pack it up as plugin, or add it to AR::Base (would make sense)

Comment: Nice idea for a general solution

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods in ActiveRecord that come in handy in cases like these, `attr_protected` and `attr_accessible`.

You use them like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :fname, :lname #Allow mass-assignment
    attr_protected :secret #Do not allow mass-assignment
end

model = MyModel.new(:fname => "Firstname", :lname => "Lastname", :secret => "haha")
puts model.fname # "Firstname"
puts model.lname # "Lastname"
puts model.secret = nil # Can not be set through mass-assignment
model.secret = "mysecret" # May only be assigned like this
puts model.secret # "mysecret"
```

However, if you only need this functionality at one place, then Salil's solution will work just as well.

One thing to note is that you should use attr_acessible to whitelist attributes that are OK to mass-assign, and make every other attribute protected. By doing so, you hinder mean people for updating data they are not supposed to touch.

See [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) for more info.

Comment: This is the best answer of all provided ones, no hacking and works at the model level, which is where this kind of code should be.

Answer (score 1):

Use Hash parameters of the update_attributes

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.update_attributes(:fname=>params[:user][:fname], :lname=>params[:user][:lname])
```

Comment: sorry, I would like to know, what is the @@user mean? why not @user only. thank you.

Comment: It is wrong, it should be something like `@user.update_attributes(...)`, like you used in your example.

Comment: @Tattat:- it's just typo here sorry. but if i am not wrong  `@@` variable are used to represent as `Global Variables in rails`

Comment: O... I see... I misunderstand the @@ is a new stuff. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How is the user updated in your code? Since you are using `User.update_attributes(..)` without any id, it is impossible to find the record/user you want to update...

Comment: @Veger :- it's by mistake it should be `@user.update_attributes` thanx anyway :)

Comment: @@ is not a global variable, it is a class variable. Global variables in ruby start with a $ character.

Answer (score 0):

You can [delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002870) unwanted attributes from the `param[:user]` Hash:

```
# ...
attributes = params[:user]
gender = attributes.delete :gender
raise SomeError unless gender.blank?
if @user.update_attributes(attributes)
  # ...
end
# ...
```

This code removes `:gender` from the Hash and checks if it is filled in. If so, an exception is raised. Of course you could give a nice warning or silently ignore the fact that the gender was filled in.